# How can I proof a difficult big o notation?

Tags: math, big-o, proof

I can easily understand how to proof a simple big o notation like n<sup>5</sup> + 3n<sup>3</sup> ∈ O(n<sup>5</sup>).

But how can I proof something more complex like 3<sup>n</sup> or 2<sup>n</sup> ∉ O(n<sup>k</sup>)?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [math.se](https://math.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Hint for exponentials: see *L'Hopital's Rule*

Answer (score 2):

Use a proof by contradiction.

Let's prove that 2<sup>n</sup> ∉ O(n<sup>2</sup>).  We assume the opposite, and deduce a contradiction from a consequence.

So: assumption: there exists M and n<sub>0</sub> such that 2<sup>n</sup> < M n<sup>2</sup> for all n >= n<sub>0</sub>.

Let x be an number such that x > 5, and x > n<sub>0</sub> and 2<sup>x</sup> > 4 M.  Do you agree that such a number must exist?

Finish off the proof by deducing a contradiction based on the inequality that 2<sup>2x</sup> < 4 M x<sup>2</sup> by assumption.

Now do the analogous proof for k = 3.  Then do it for k = 4.  Then generalize your result for all k.